# Convert selected data grid view row into data row in C#

Tags: c#

In data grid view shows the list of rows which is fetched from the database. I have selected a row in the data grid view. I have to pass the selected row info into another class. I have a property to set the selected row, I got the selected row info from the property and then bind the values into the control.

Is it possible to convert the selected data grid view row into data row?

Which one is best for this situations:

1. Selected data grid view row into a data table.
2. Selected data grid view row into an object.
3. Selected data grid view row into a data row array.(But I have only one record during selection.)

Comment: Your question is vague. You should be able to convert a `DataGridView` row to whatever you need. What are you doing with this data row? Do you need to keep/store this row info for processing later? DataTable; Object or DataRow array all depend on what your requirements are. You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have to bind the selected data row in the control. Thanks for the link. "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable".

Answer (score 1):

set a DataTable in DataGridView.DataSource property, **before** populate data.
then you not need export data, just use the source DataTable. also for selected row you can use `(DataRow)dgv.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have implemented like this.
 DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dg.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow drSelected = currentDataRowView.Row;